# Refresh Paint after Scroll is Completed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll, datagridview, paint

I have a datagridview which places a black border around selected cell(s). My code works fine, up until I scroll while making my selection. My top border disappears when I scroll down while making a selection, which is not a problem at this point, because it shows that there are more selected cells out of view, the problem I have is once I've made my selection and then return to the top, the top border never returns. I've noticed that on enter to a cell, the dgv repaints, and this I assume is the reason why my top border is not painting, because it is out of view and once I scroll back to the top, I'm not entering any new cells, so the top border never repaints.

So I added a scroll event to refresh my dgv paint, but this seems to repaint then scroll and not scroll the repaint, which results in even further selected cell borders not displayed.

So my question is, is there a way to trigger the repaint after the scroll is complete?

Below is my code, not sure if it is relevant to show, but here it is.

```
    Private Sub dgvdefault_paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    With dgvdefault

        ' draw border around dgv
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(penborder, 0, 0, .Width - 1, .Height - 1)


        For Each cell In .SelectedCells

            ' get cell position and size

            a = cell.rowindex
            b = cell.columnindex

            Dim myrect As Rectangle = (.GetCellDisplayRectangle(b, a, False))
            Dim dgvdefault_headerrectangle As Rectangle = (.GetCellDisplayRectangle(-1, -1, False))

            ' top border

            If a = 0 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1)
            ElseIf .Rows(a - 1).Cells(b).Selected = False Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1)
            End If

            ' bottom border

            If a = .RowCount - 1 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height)
            ElseIf .Rows(a + 1).Cells(b).Selected = False Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height)
            End If

            ' left border

            If b = 0 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height)
            ElseIf .Rows(a).Cells(b - 1).Selected = False Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1, myrect.X - 1, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height)
            End If

            ' right border

            If b = .ColumnCount - 1 Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height)
            ElseIf .Rows(a).Cells(b + 1).Selected = False Then
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1, myrect.X - 1 + myrect.Width, myrect.Y - 1 + myrect.Height)
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub dgvdefault_scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs)

    dgvdefault.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Comment: play with : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0260__GUI/ValuechangeeventVericalHorizontalscrollbar.htm

Comment: To show up correctly, the `Paint` event has to trigger after the scroll. Otherwise you would't see the correct items.

Comment: You are just not doing this correctly.  Use the CellPainting event instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans for your reply, the reason I have not used cellpainting is because I assumed I would only be able to draw within a specific cell, whereas my border will draw slightly outside the cell. I'm going to look into this now however, to see if I can get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollEventArgs has a type enumeration that you can evaluate in a conditional branch.

Edit* The datagridview won't show all scroll event types, therefore we use reflection to add a listener to the internal components event.

Example:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Imports System.Reflection
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 10
        For i As Integer = 0 To 100
            Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        DGVAddListener(DataGridView1)
    End Sub
    Public Function DGVAddListener(dataGridView As DataGridView) As Boolean
        Dim pInfo As PropertyInfo = dataGridView.GetType.GetProperty("VerticalScrollBar", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        If pInfo Is Nothing Then Return False
        Dim dgvScrollBar As ScrollBar = CType(pInfo.GetValue(dataGridView, Nothing), ScrollBar)
        If dgvScrollBar is Nothing then Return False 
        AddHandler dgvScrollBar.Scroll, New ScrollEventHandler(AddressOf dgv_Scroll)
        Return True
    End Function
    Public Sub dgv_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Type
            Case ScrollEventType.EndScroll
                MsgBox("Scroll End!")
            Case ScrollEventType.First
            Case ScrollEventType.LargeDecrement
            Case ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement
            Case ScrollEventType.Last
            Case ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement
            Case ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement
            Case ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition
            Case ScrollEventType.ThumbTrack
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Paul for your answer, but I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried case scrolleventtype.endscroll msgbox("scrollend") and If e.Type = ScrollEventType.EndScroll Then msgbox("scrollend"), but neither seem to work. After being unable to get this to work, I went online and someone said that the endscroll doesn't work for datagridviews, but I don't know how true this is. Any suggestion to what might be going wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Hi Jarron, I added a modification that should raise the EndScroll event now.  I edited my original answer.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to add one for both Vertical and Horizontal so if you want to catch both you need 2 listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Properly not the best answer, but this is what I've come up with to get my dgv to refresh post scrolling, which seems to work well (very small amount of delay).

```
Private Sub dgvdefault_scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs)
    AddHandler timer1.Tick, AddressOf timer1_tick
End Sub
Private Sub timer1_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    dgvdefault.Refresh()
    RemoveHandler timer1.Tick, AddressOf timer1_tick
End Sub
```

Comment: Change timer1.Interval to equal 1 and I could not see any delay.